# variavel pegar determinado numeros

Tags: javascript

Boa tarde pessoal.

Preciso que uma variável pegue sempre um determinado número de uma ordem, por exemplo:

o usuário digita `123456789`

> **variavel a**: pegara sempre o primeiro número da série, ou seja, `1`
>
> **variavel b**: pegara sempre o segundo número da série, ou seja, `2`

e assim sucessivamente.

Comment: Pode mostrar o que você já tentou, qual a dúvida?

Comment: isso é para algum exercício? caso contrário não tem motivos para criar uma variável para cada ocorrência e sim um array

Answer (score 3):

O método `split` separa caracteres de uma palavra quando o delimitador não é informado. Assim:

```
var variavel = "123456789";
var caractere = variavel.split(''); // aqui ele separa a string

var variavel_A = caractere[0]; // primeiro caractere
var variavel_B = caractere[1]; // segundo caractere
var variavel_C = caractere[2]; // terceiro caractere
var variavel_D = caractere[3]; // quarto caractere

alert(variavel_A ); // retornará "1" 
alert(variavel_B); // retornará "2"
alert(variavel_C); // retornará "3"
alert(variavel_D); // retornará "4"
```

Se a variável for um número, você precisará transforma-lo em uma string antes de usar o `split`. Assim:

```
var num = 123456789; // numero
var variavel = num.toString(); // transforma em string
var caractere = variavel.split(''); // usa o split()
```

Você também pode usar o `charAt`, deste modo:

```
var variavel = "123456789";

var variavel_A = variavel.charAt(0); // primeiro caractere
var variavel_B = variavel.charAt(1); // segundo caractere
var variavel_C = variavel.charAt(2); // terceiro caractere
var variavel_D = variavel.charAt(3); // quarto caractere
```

Existe um modo mais indicado caso a variável seja uma `String`:

Conforme sugerido pelo @Isac e pelo @lazyFox.

> você também pode usar o operador de indexação diretamente sobre uma
>   `string`, sem a necessidade de usar o `split` ou `chatAt`

Deste modo:

```
var variavel = "123456789";
alert(variavel[0]); // retorna 1
```

Comment: Pode usar o operador de indexação diretamente sobre uma `string`, sem ter que fazer `.split('')` primeiro.

Comment: Nao sabia @Isac. Vou melhorar a resposta.

Comment: Se a variável já for uma string, nem precisa do charAt :) ou seja `"1234"[0]`.  `var a = 1234; a = a.toString()[0]`

Comment: @lazyFox kkkkk... vivendo e aprendendo... Vou editar a resposta e citar isso.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode criar a quantidade de variáveis, dinamicamente, em função da quantidade de dígitos na string

```js
 var variavel = "123456789";
 //quantidade de dígitos na variável acima
 var n = variavel.length;
 var caractere = variavel.split('');
  
  //criando as variáveis dinamicamente
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
  var char_A = i+1;
  var letra = (String.fromCharCode(char_A+64))
  window["variavel" + letra] = (caractere[i]);
  }
  
 //verificando algumas variaveis 
 console.log( "O valor da variavelA é " + variavelA);

    console.log( "O valor da variavelB é " + variavelB);
 
 console.log( "O valor da variavelE é " + variavelE);
  
  
   
  //Para recuperar os valores de todas as variáveis
  for (var i = 0; i <n; i++)
  {
  var char_A = i+1;
  var letra = (String.fromCharCode(char_A+64))
  console.log(window["variavel" + letra]);
  }
```

O método [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) divide um objeto String em um array de strings ao separar a string em substrings.

O método [String.fromCharCode()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) retorna uma string criada ao usar uma sequencia específica de valores Unicode.